# Disable IntelliJ SQL Inspections not working

Tags: intellij-idea

With IntelliJ 2017.1, with the following simple Scala file:

```
package demopackage

import slick.jdbc.DerbyProfile.api._

object SqlInspection {
  val query =
    sql"""
         |select my_col
         |from my_table as table_alias
      """.stripMargin
}
```

I get an inspection error: `unexpected 'value'`.

I get the red error bar on the right scroll bar and the word `table_alias` has a red squiggle underline.

If I reformat the sql to a single line, the inspection error goes away.

This seems like a completely bogus inspection, so I'd like to disable.

In Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections, I have disabled absolutely everything and I still get this inspection error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually is not an inspection, but SQL parser error, because of a pipe margin characters in multiline string, so it can not be disabled via inspection settings. I've filled the [IDEA-170738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170738) request for better handling of such cases. A workaround without modifying the code is to either [un-inject](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-language-injections.html?search=inject#d627057e207) SQL language from the string or [set highlighting level for the file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html?search=highlighting%20level) to **None**.